# Open file from minifilter during the instance_setup

Tags: driver, minifilter

I am new in minifilter development and I am wondering if I can read some information from a xml/txt file in the *instance_setup* function. The idea is to pass information to the minifilter from a config file at startup.

*fopen()* is not working because my minifilter does not allow me to import this function. The compiler of my Visual Studio raises *unresolved external symbol*.

Is it not possible to open files from a minifilter? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to use `FltCreateFile/FltReadFile` or `ZwCreateFile/ZwReadFile`

Comment: After reading the FltReadFile documentation in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/fltkernel/nf-fltkernel-fltreadfile, it seems that the file must be already opened to read from it, which is not the case. The problem I have is that I need to open the file from the minifilter (and then read from it)

Comment: You need to use FltCreateFile first bro... Just like user mode application